# Zend Framework Firebird Example

Tags: php, zend-framework, firebird

I am new to Zend.  I'm using Zend 1.11 and trying to successfully connect to a Firebird database.  As far as I can tell I have all the php_interbase stuff enabled.  I see the ZendX firebird adapter, but I still get this message

> Warning: include_once(Zend\Db\Adapter\Php\Firebird.php)
>   [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\wamp\bin\php\Zend_Framework\library\Zend\Loader.php on
>   line 146

As if it has no idea what adapter I'm speaking of.

I'm using this in my boot strap

```
    protected function _initDb()
{
    $this->bootstrap('config');
    $config = $this->getResource('config');

    $db = Zend_Db::factory('Php_Firebird', array(
        'host'     => $config->Database->Server,
        'username' => $config->Database->Username,
        'password' => $config->Database->Password,
        'dbname'   => $config->Database->DBName
    ));

    return $db;
}
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact this is ZendX stuff not Zend\db stuff but I cannot find an example of it. Or from the factory function using a ZendX adapter.  I tried to use 'Php_Interbase' but that was not found either (and I dont see it in the folders anyway). And I tried Pdo_Firebird as well which of course didnt work.

Has someone done this that can point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add `adapterNamespace` to the configuration array you are passing to the factory. [See the 3rd example here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.connecting.factory), also remove `'PHP_'` from the adapter name, so your call to the factory should look like this:-

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Firebird', array(
        'host' => $config->Database->Server,
        'username' => $config->Database->Username,
        'password' => $config->Database->Password,
        'dbname' => $config->Database->DBName,
        'adapterNamespace' => 'ZendX_Db_Adapter'
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$db = new ZendX_Db_Adapter_Firebird(array(
    //config part
));
```